# Get the first real number from a series of files

Tags: bash, file, unix

I try to take the first number from each file.dat of the form:

```
  5.01       1     56.413481000  -0.00063400   0.00095770
  5.01       2     61.193808800   0.00102170   0.00078280
  5.01       3     65.974136600  -0.00108170   0.00102620
  5.01       4     70.754464300   0.00082490   0.00103630
```

and then use this number (`5.01`) as the title of a .png file.

I use a bash script and I know the command `line=$(head -n 1 $f)` as found in a question here, but this take to me the first line of the file `$f`.

In this case also the space in the line is saved and the .png file title became:

`plot  5.01       1     56.413481000  -0.00063400   0.00095770.png`

There is some way to take only 5.01 and have a trim title for the plot?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably just do it with `perl`:

```
VAL=$( echo "$line" | perl -pe 's/^[^\d]+//g;s/[^\d\.].*$//' )
```

Something like that anyway.

Should remove:

- anything that isn't a digit from the start of line.
- Anything not-digit or not `.` to the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

Or with grep:

```
grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" file.dat | head -1
```

Edit:
Testing without the head -1 for a oneline input:

```
echo "  5.01       2     61.193808800   0.00102170   0.00078280" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
5.01
61.193808800
0.00102170
0.00078280
```

Using head -1 will return the first match on the first line.

When you know the match will be on the  first line, so can we ignore files with an incorrect first line (and don't grep through complete files):
Make a two-headed monster:

```
head -1 | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" file.dat | head -1
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the first field, assuming they are tab separated:

```
val=$(head -n 1 $f | cut -f 1)
```

or, if they are space separated instead:

```
val=$(head -n 1 $f | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

OR you can avoid calling any extra processes and keep all data manipulation in the `bash` shell with

```
  while read realNum restOfLine ; 
     break
  done < $f

  echo $realNum
```

This grabs the first "word" and puts the remaining into "restOfLine".
The `break` ensures that you only read the first line of the file.

IHTH

Comment: Is there a way of doing this that validates whether the first 'word' grabbed is actually numeric? (asking out of curiosity more than anything).

Comment: @Sobrique: Regex testing with `[[ "$realNum" =~ $pattern ]]` should work, for the right `$pattern`.

Comment: @Sobrique : Yes, you can validate as BenjaminW. indicates, or with shell glob chars inside of a case statement (still no extra processes ;-) ). OR you could add a line `realNum=${realNum%%[^0-9.]}` and similar for the right side of variable. The reason I didn't include that in my answer is that is not clear what the O.P. would want to do in case of bad input: try the next line, stop all processing, or skip to next file and that level of processing is not hinted at in the Q. Good luck to all!